Probability that one estimator is larger than another
Imagine having $n$ independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) observations from a variable $X$, which in the population follows a Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. For $\sigma^2$, the maximum likelihood estimator is $\hat{\sigma}^2$ equal to the sample variance $D = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i} (x_i - \bar{x})^2$. It is known that often $S^2$, which equals $\frac{D}{n-1}$, is preferred instead. Indeed, $S^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$, and in the Normal case, $\mathrm{Var}(S^2) = \frac{2 \sigma^4}{n - 1}$.
What is the value of the probability $P(\hat{\sigma}^2 > S^2)$?

I think you meant $S^2 = \frac{n D}{n-1}$.  The unbiased estimator, $S^2$, is therefore always greater than $D$.

Seems to me that $D<S^2$ always.
